# Convert timestamp to datetime with sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have a log file, and each line in it is like:

```
timestamp=1356431101, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
```

Now I want to use sed to replace timestamp wth human-readable datetime:

```
timestamp=2012-12-24 10:00:00, entity=xxx, event:xxxxx
```

My command is:

```
sed "s/^timestamp=\([0-9]\{10\}\),/timestamp=\`date +%D --date=@\1\`,/"
```

But the problem is that the `\1` can not be substituted by the 10-digits timestamp, instead, it is always treated as digit `1`. Can anyone tell me how to tackle this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `sed` does not support backticks.  The shell is invoking date with the `1` in its parameter list and passing the result to `sed`.  Use a different tool.  (Or recognize that epoch time stamps *are* human readable!)

Comment: Since `1356431101 = 2012-12-25 10:25:01 +00:00`, it is far from clear that there's any time zone where you can get the conversion you specify in the example (you can't ordinarily specify a time zone with an offset that's not a multiple of 60 seconds).  As others have said, `sed` is not the correct tool for this task.  I'd use Perl, but you could use Python or Ruby or any of the modern scripting languages; any of these would be better suited to the task than `sed` is (and I like `sed`, but I recognize its limitations).

Answer (score 4):

try

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/^/echo "/; s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)/`date -d @\1`/; s/$/"/' | bash
```

Answer (score 3):

awk is better for these stuff, if acceptable:

```
awk -F, '{x=$1;sub(/.*=/,"",$1);sub(/=.*/,strftime("=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1),x);$1=x;}1' OFS=, file
```

A sample result:

```
$ cat file
timestamp=1356431101, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
timestamp=1354770380, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
```

On running the command:

```
$ awk -F, '{x=$1;sub(/.*=/,"",$1);sub(/=.*/,strftime("=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1),x);$1=x;}1' OFS=, file
timestamp=2012-12-25 15:55:01, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
timestamp=2012-12-06 10:36:20, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
```

The first `sub` command extracts the timestamp. The second using the `strftime` replaces the timestamp with the date and time. `1` is used to print every line.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp manipulation is best done with a more modern programming language, like Perl or Ruby. However, if you have GNU awk, you could do this using the `strftime()` function:

```
awk '{ sub(/[0-9]{10}/, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr($0,11,10))) }1' file
```

Results:

```
timestamp=2012-12-25 20:25:01, entity=xxx, event: xxxxxx
```

---

You can also read more about GNU awk's time functions here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer the `awk` approach, but for completeness a `perl` solution looks like:

```
perl -Mposix -pe 's/([0-9]{10})/POSIX::strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime($1))/eg'
```

If you want to match the leading "timestamp=" to limit the replacements (although this does not appear necessary given the sample input), you can use: `'s/(?:timestamp=)([0-9]*)/...`